# Is there a way to validate each row of a spark dataframe?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My activity setup :

1. I have a text file containing multiple json entries .
2. I want to access each json entry and verify its key value pair .

Is there a way to do this using Pyspark ?

I tried to load the txt file by reading it into a spark session and validating its schema using the  dataframe.schema() function. But I recently learnt that dataframe.schema() does data sampling and doesnt validate all the records in the dataframe.

Comment: It will be easier if you add some example code so that, contributors need not spend time in creating the dataframe with hardcoding samples. Also, its easy to misinterpret the input data if someone has to imagine.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off using a framework like Deequ (https://github.com/awslabs/python-deequ) to test your dataset.

Comment: I dont think deequ/pydeequ support schema validation , hence I did not take that approach . Please let me know if my understanding is incorrect.
I m trying validate if the json entries of my text file have all required key value pairs.

Comment: You should be able to read the file as a string, then you should be able to use the from_json function (https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/from_json.html) to parse the string to json. You have optoins as mode and columnNameOfCorruptRecord to get the results of the parsing.